# Pagination issue in Django

Tags: python, django, pagination

I have a database in my Django project on which I am making queries. I would like to display the responses in different pages.

If the request is "none", the pagination works flawlessly.

But whenever I pass a query, first page displays the responses I am looking for but next pages are behaving like request were "none".

Here is my `views.py`

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('query')    

    if not query:
        products_list= Product.objects.all()        
    else:        
        products_list = Product.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)
    if not products_list.exists():
        products_list = Product.objects.filter(brand__icontains=query)

    title = "Results:  %s" % query

    paginator = Paginator(products_list, 9)
    page = request.GET.get('page',1)

    try:
        products = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:        
        products = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:        
        products = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        'products': products,
        'title': title,
        'paginate': True,
    }
    return render(request, 'finder/search.html', context)
```

And the html:

```
<nav aria-label="">
  <ul class="pager">
    {% if products.has_previous %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ products.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if products.has_next %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ products.next_page_number }}">Next</a></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your query parameter also in your template, as otherwise you are not going to get query param in your function

```
   context = {
        'products': products,
        'title': title,
        'paginate': True,
        'query': query
    }
```

---

```
<nav aria-label="">
  <ul class="pager">
    {% if products.has_previous %}
        <li><a href="?query={{query}}&page={{ products.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a></li>
    {% endif %}
```